# Relation of absolute convergence to expected value.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

**Claim:** If $X_n \overset{\text{a.s.}}{\longrightarrow} X$ then $\mathbf{E}[\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n] = \mathbf{E}[X]$.

**Question:** Is this true? Below is a proof, but I'm worried that I made a mistake. Specifically, I'm worried about what happens when $\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n$ does not always exist---in this proof this only occurs for events $\omega$ in a measure zero set, so I can ignore this... right?

**Proof:**

Let $X_n$ (for all $n$) and $X$ be random variables on the probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, P)$ and let $\mathcal A = \{\omega \in \Omega : \lim_{n\to\infty}X_n = X\}$. Then:
\begin{align}
    \mathbf{E}\left [ \lim_{n\to\infty} X_n \right ]=& \int_\Omega \lim_{n\to\infty}X_n \mbox{d}P\\
    =& \int_{\mathcal A} \lim_{n\to\infty}X_n \mbox{d}P + \int_{\Omega \setminus \mathcal A} \lim_{n\to\infty}X_n \mbox{d}P.
\end{align}
For the first term, notice that for all $\omega \in \mathcal A$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n = X$. For the second term, notice that by the assumption that $X_n\overset{\text{a.s.}}{\longrightarrow} X$, we have that $\Omega \setminus \mathcal A$ has measure zero. So:
\begin{align}
    \mathbf{E}\left [ \lim_{n\to\infty} X_n \right ]=& \int_{\mathcal A} X\mbox{d}P\\
    =& \int_{\mathcal A} X \mbox{d}P + \int_{\Omega \setminus \mathcal A} X \mbox{d}P\\
    =& \mathbf{E}[X].
\end{align}

Comment: Your proof is right. But normally we prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbf{E}[X_n] = \mathbf{E}[X]$.

Comment: @hermes That scares me a little... can't we not swap the orders of limits and expected values without additional assumptions---e.g. that $X_n$ is bounded?

Comment: Hermes means that your proof is right, but it proves only a very minor factoid.  What we normally want to prove is much more:  We want to show we can swap the limit and expectation.  For that, we do indeed need additional conditions such as boundedness of $X_n$ (bounded convergence theorem) or some alternative condition to apply the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: What about, in the above, arguing that $\mathbb{E} X$ is actually defined (maybe by writing it as assumption)? Not all r.v.'s are in $L^1$.